# Is that good to create log file per user in a web application

Tags: java, logging

when error happen, I found it's hard to track problems in a big and mixed(session) log file ?
So, I want to create a log file for every user, but i am afraid If I do so will have a great impact on performance.
there are 1000+ users, the max numbers of users online since now is below 100

sorry for my english, I hope you guys can understand what I'm talking about...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily using [Logback's MDC](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) or Log4j's MDC. Don't worry, this shouldn't impact performance.

Comment: Log4J ist great for this. I use the MDC for user logging a lot and together with a grep you can easily see the logs for a spezific user

Answer (score 3):

Instead of logging to separate files, why don't you log to a database as suggested in these answers.
[log4net - want to create a log file per web application user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307279/log4net-want-to-create-a-log-file-per-web-application-user)

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on whether or not the information "which user was active when error X happend" is essential to fixing the problem. If it's not then do not use user specific logfiles.

The better solution would be to take another look at the application itself - if there are that many problems occuring on a production system you really have a problem with the overall quality of your application. Splitting the logging output into different files is trying to treat the symptoms but not the problem itself.

Comment: I don't think that is a helpful answer. Firstly you are assuming that their log file is full of errors where it might just be full of other non-related info that is causing a lot of 'noise' when trying to debug a specific problem. Also 'take a look at the application itself' is much help, I'm assuming that is what they are trying to do.